# Converter uma lista de listas em uma só lista

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou a trabalhar em Python 2.7.
Tenho este resultado:

```
Resultado=[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]
```

Como posso transformar isto numa lista? E obter o seguinte:

```
Lista=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para fazer uma só lista de:

```
Resultado=[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]
```

Faça (escusa de importar libs externas para isto, isto é o que recomendo):

```
Lista = [item for sublista in Resultado for item in sublista]
```

Alternativas:

```
Lista = []
for i in Resultado:
    Lista.extend(i)

print Lista  #['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Ou:

```
Lista = []
[Lista.extend(i) for i in Resultado]

print Lista  #['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria isso usando o método `chain` do `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain

Resultado  = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]

Lista = list(chain(*Resultado))

print (Lista); # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Só para obter mais informações a respeito de como pesquisar caso necesário, o nome dessa operação em inglês se chama `flatten`. Significa que você está transformando uma lista multinível em uma lista unidimensional.