# Python - Transformar lista de listas em uma unica lista

Tags: python

Como posso transformar uma lista de listas em uma unica lista?

Preciso transformar isso:

```
lista = [["Danilo","Gilson"],["Eduarda",["Costa","Otávio"]]]
```

nisso:

```
lista = ["Danilo","Gilson","Eduarda","Costa","Otávio"]
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164539/como-unir-v%C3%A1rias-listas-em-uma-matriz isso te ajudaria Danilo ?

Comment: Não, minha duvida é parecida com essa, mas ainda sim não resolveu meu problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131258/converter-uma-lista-de-listas-em-uma-s%C3%B3-lista

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Aplanar lista de listas. É possível uma solução mais concisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281987/aplanar-lista-de-listas-%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-uma-solu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-mais-concisa)

Answer (score 1):

Tentei abstrair para uma função e uma das formas seria essa:

```
def lista_unica(lista):
    result = []
    for item in lista:
        if (isinstance(item, (list, tuple))):
            result = lista.extend(item)
        else:
            result.append(item)
    return result


>>> lista = [["Danilo","Gilson"],["Eduarda",["Costa","Otávio"]]]
>>> print(lista_unica(lista)) 
['Danilo', 'Gilson', 'Eduarda', 'Costa', 'Otávio']
```

Outa maneira seria utilizar recursão que e efetuar somente chamadas ao método `append`.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando recursividade e [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) fica bem curtinho:

```
def lista_simples(lista):
    if isinstance(lista, list):
        return [sub_elem for elem in lista for sub_elem in lista_simples(elem)]
    else:
        return [lista]

lista = [["Danilo","Gilson"],["Eduarda",["Costa","Otávio"]]]
resultado = lista_simples(lista)
print(resultado) # ['Danilo', 'Gilson', 'Eduarda', 'Costa', 'Otávio']
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZWcSTo)

Por simplicidade deixei apenas o teste com o tipo `list`. Se quiser com que a função funcione para qualquer iteravel pode trocar para `isinstance(lista, Iterable)` mas terá que desconsiderar quando for uma `string` que também é um iterável. Nesse caso o ideal seria então:

```
if isinstance(lista, Iterable) and not isinstance(lista, str):
```

E acrescentando o `import` para o `Iterable`

```
from collections import Iterable
```